# Swing components overlapping when content in changed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm having a problem when an event will change the content of a component, like changing a JLabel's name, removing buttons from a Jpanel then adding another component.

Here is my initial JFrame.
[image: Normal frame]

Here is what my JFrame looks when components overlaps every time there is an event.
[image: Normal frame]

I'm using this code to temporarily solve my problem, but of course this is not a good idea by just resizing.

```
setSize(panelWidth + 1, panelHeight + 1);
setSize(panelWidth, panelHeight);
```

I'm wondering what causes this problem and how can I address this?

NOTE: I'm using layout manager. The panel with buttons is using Grid Layout and most of other is using Grid Bag Layout.

UPDATE:Removing `setOpaque(true)` fix the overlapping on the panel at top. What remains is the panel with the buttons. I'm using `GridLayout` with only 1 column.

Here is some of my code for displaying the buttons at `pnlButtons`.

```
    private void initializeShoppingModeButtons() {
    pnlButtons.removeAll();
    pnlButtons.add(btnSearchProduct);
    pnlButtons.add(btnManualInput);
    pnlButtons.add(btnCheckOut);
}

private void initializeProductMenuButtons() {
    pnlButtons.removeAll();
    pnlButtons.add(btnSearchProduct);
    pnlButtons.add(btnViewIndividual);
    pnlButtons.add(btnAlternative);
    pnlButtons.add(btnDisplayInfo);
    pnlButtons.add(btnCancel);
}
```

Comment: Do you use `LayoutManager` or you add components to null Layout?

Comment: That kind of issues can happen for example when the components do not obey the opaqueness contract.

Comment: Yes, I'm using layout manager.

Comment: Almost impossible to tell without some code.

Comment: @kiheru It solves some of my problems, but the panel with buttons still remain overlapping. Tnx anyway.

Comment: still this question isn't answerbale, without your SSCCE/MCVE/MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JComponents

Comment: pnlButtons.removeAll(); then pnlButtons.revalidate() and repaint() must be called as last code lines, after all changes to the visible Swing GUI is done

Comment: `revalidate()` is for what? `repaint` solves my problem.

Comment: `revalidate()` tells the layout managers to re-layout their components.

Answer (score 5):

one of possible issues is very simple code snipped

```
private void initializeProductMenuButtons() {
    pnlButtons.removeAll();
    pnlButtons.add(btnSearchProduct);
    pnlButtons.add(btnViewIndividual);
    pnlButtons.add(btnAlternative);
    pnlButtons.add(btnDisplayInfo);
    pnlButtons.add(btnCancel);
}
```

should be

```
private void initializeProductMenuButtons() {
    pnlButtons.removeAll();
    pnlButtons.add(btnSearchProduct);
    pnlButtons.add(btnViewIndividual);
    pnlButtons.add(btnAlternative);
    pnlButtons.add(btnDisplayInfo);
    pnlButtons.add(btnCancel);
    pnlButtons.revalidate();
    pnlButtons.repaint();
}
```

- Swings APIs haven't any notifier that content of container is changed

  1. e.g. `JComponents` are removed, removed and added, some kinds of relayout (change ordering of, e.i.)
  2. `revalidate();` and `repaint();` will notify used `LayoutManager`, use that as last code lines, after all changes to Swing GUI are done
- nothing cleaver without your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), [MCVE/MCTRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Edit 1st.

- have look at use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)  for switching between views

Comment: +1 :) Please consider add a comment about this line: `setSize(panelWidth + 1, panelHeight + 1);`. Developers never should calculate any width/height as this task is done by layout managers.